# Get the columns that were actually updated to a different value?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, python-3.x, psycopg2

I'm running something like this:

```
cursor.execute(
    '''
    UPDATE my_table
    SET name=%s, about=%s, title=%s
    WHERE id=%s
    ''',
    (name, about, title, id_)
)
```

Which is guaranteed to only update one row, since it's doing the update based on the `id` primary key.

However,  most of the time only one of the fields *actually* changes, i.e. the `about` and `title` are "updated" to the same value they were already, and only `name` has actually changed.

How can I get which of the columns actually changed? This is needed to log every individual change.

Comment: So you want to get something like a list of tuples `(row, column_name)`?

Comment: Yeah, but I just added *"Which is guaranteed to only update one row, since it's doing the update based on the `id` primary key."*, so for me personally it's enough to just get a list of column names.

Comment: Have you tried adding in Returning name, about, title; after the Where clause?

Comment: postgres updates the row, not columns. so the whole tuple get overwritten. If you want to compare if values updated did not change, use returning * and select in CTE?..

Comment: Using `returning` seems to return the *updated* values, which don't really help me since I already know them.

Comment: returning * will return all values from update. I'll give you an example in answer - wait a sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can select values before update and using `RETURNING *` compare values in final query, like here:

```
t=# create table m1 (i int, e int);
CREATE TABLE
Time: 1.855 ms
t=# insert into m1 select 1,2;
INSERT 0 1
Time: 1.037 ms
t=# begin;
BEGIN
t=# with o as (select * from m1 where i=1)
,u as (update m1 set e=3 where i=1 returning *)
select * from o
join u on o.i = u.i
;
 i | e | i | e
---+---+---+---
 1 | 2 | 1 | 3
(1 row)
```

so you can put logic against `u.e <> o.e` or alike

Comment: Ah this works, I didn't realize to select it beforehand like so. Thanks :)